# how to send data from PC to raspberry pi?

Tags: opencv, server, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to send 1 byte data (maybe char) from PC to raspberry pi.
There are many way to send data but I am using the streaming server(which is used for mjpg-stream) so I'd like to use the streaming server. Can I send data through the streaming server? or what is the best way(simple way) to send data from PC to Pi. Server, WiFi, Bluetooth..and so on.
Plus I access Pi with ssh.

Hear's what I'm doing.

1. Take videos from Pi camera.
2. mjpg-stream
3. OpenCV video processing on PC (python). (Action analysis..)
4. Send the result as simple data like 1, 2 and 3 (1 byte)... to raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: Create a socket between the PC and Raspi and write the byte on there.

Comment: you could use Thrift or gRPC, for example

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Serialize your data. Make sure whatever serializer you are using is endian agnostic, especially since you will be communicating with a RPi;
2. Create a server/client (socket). I recommend using ZeroMQ. There are many, many tutorials on this, but just don't reinvent the wheel with this. Use a helper library.
3. Send the data over the socket.
4. De-serialize the data using the same serializer used in step 1.

As far as serialization libraries go, I like Cereal or Protocol Buffers.

Using the above methods, I've even managed to send multiple live video streams over one 1000 Mbps connection with minimal processing overhead.

Comment: I have tried serializing before. Its ridiculously slow. I ended up using gstreamer which is pretty awesome and syncs well with OpenCV.